# django forms excluded field - error adding values to them via form instance

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models 'Student'  and 'Abc' .

```
class Abc(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    nickname = models.CharField(max_length=20)

ClassAbcForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('name', 'nickname')  # Note that I didnt include student field.
```

I didnt include 'student' field as that can be populated via view.  The user should just
enter 'name' and 'nickname' fields. So, I included only those fields to be shown in the form by settings the 'fields' in the Meta class.

I tried like below in the views :

```
student = student_instance
student_id = id
```

But, got the error.

If I add 'student' to the fields in the form, then it is working fine.  Whats the solution ?

Comment: Post your view code and the full error please

Comment: Yes, please post the error.

Comment: Post you view code better

Answer (score 0):

```
ClassAbcForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Abc //should be Abc not Student
        fields = ('name', 'nickname')

def view_name(request):
    student = Student(student_id=student_id) //define first student here
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassAbcForm(request.POST, instance=student)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    ................
```